# Multiple schemes found but you haven't specified one in Teamcity Xcode Project

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, teamcity, fastlane

I'm using Teamcity for Continuous Integration for my iOS project.

In this i've used below **fastlane** commands to upload build to TestFlight.

```
export PATH="$HOME/.fastlane/bin:$PATH"
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
bundle exec fastlane init
bundle exec fastlane sigh --username xxx@xxxx.com --team_id ABCDEFGH
bundle exec fastlane sigh download_all
bundle exec fastlane gym
bundle exec fastlane pilot upload
```

In

> fastlane gym

step, it's failing because of Multiple scheme found issue.

[image]

But I've checked my scheme. I've single shared scheme only.

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution after some research. The actual fastlane commands are,

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
bundle exec fastlane init
bundle exec fastlane sigh --username xxx@xxxx.com --team_id ABCDEFGH
bundle exec fastlane sigh download_all
bundle exec fastlane gym
bundle exec fastlane pilot upload
```

removed this, and working fine

> export PATH="$HOME/.fastlane/bin:$PATH"